# Ionic 4 router destroy page programmatically

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-router

I have a sign up flow on my app. At each step I don't want the user to be able to go to the previous page, however, ionic keeps these pages "alive" and the user is able to go back either by swiping from left to right or using the back button on their phone.

I transition each user using ionic's routing system:

```
 this.router.navigateByUrl('/invite');
```

I've also tried:

```
 this.router.navigate(['/invite']);
```

and:

```
 this.router.navigateByUrl('/invite', { skipLocationChange: true });
```

It's causing me a lot of problems at the moment and I've done quite a bit of Googling and couldn't find any solutions.

Is there a way using ionic's router system to destroy a page or disallow backward navigation on *some* pages? Any advice would be great. Thank you.

Comment: I think it works with the skipLocationChange but not from the root page. So from root, navigate to another route, then from then on, the history will be replaced

Answer (score 10):

You probably solved this already, however you can use the following as well:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/invite',{
 replaceUrl : true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ionic navigation for that, they provide the functionalities.

Inject navController in constructor.

```
  constructor(
    private navCtrl: NavController,
  ) {
  }
```

Then use navigateroot, it will destroy previous page

```
this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/home', { animated: true, animationDirection: 'forward' });
```

Go through below documentation

https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/navigation

Comment: NavController is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You can use `route-guard`

This is good Example Go throuh it

https://alligator.io/angular/route-guards/

in your `routing module` add

```
const myRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: yourHomeComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard',
    component: anyComponentComponent,
    canActivate: [CanActivateRouteGuard]
  }
];
```

make your simple route gurd

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate,
         ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
         RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { MyAuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class _CanActivateRouteGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: MyAuthService) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
      return this.auth.isUserAuthenticated();
  }
}
```